# unable to get xpath of array

Tags: xml, xpath

I've been trying to get the xpath of `<Name>` but with no luck! The webservice return the below XML and we know its an array of values.

```
<ArrayOfSample xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="servername">
  <sample>
   <ID>788999</ID>
   <Name>Employee Name</Name>
  </sample>
</ArrayOfSample>
```

I've tried some tools for XPath builder but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target element resides in namespace `http://hqjed-sql01/`. You need to define a prefix, say `p`, that reference that namespace and use the prefix in the XPath :

```
//p:Name
```

Or you can ignore the namespace by using `local-name()` :

```
//*[local-name()='Name']
```

Comment: Correct, of course, (+1) but I closed question as a duplicate of a XPath namespace question with a comprehensive answer including how to set namespace prefixes in multiple languages.